# is it possible to trigger Tron smart contract from tronweb and Azure key vault

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-keyvault, tron, tronweb

i'm thinking of developing a bridge between Tron and Ethereum chains for my erc-20 token on Azure and store my private keys in Azure key vault. For ethereum i've found a nice library just for this: https://github.com/tmarkovski/ethereumjs-tx-keyvault, but will the same approach work in tronweb? tronweb uses elliptic.js for signatures:

```
export function ECKeySign(hashBytes, priKeyBytes) {
  const ec = new EC("secp256k1");
  const key = ec.keyFromPrivate(priKeyBytes, "bytes");
  const signature = key.sign(hashBytes);
  const r = signature.r;
  const s = signature.s;
  const id = signature.recoveryParam;

  let rHex = r.toString("hex");

  while (rHex.length < 64) {
    rHex = `0${rHex}`;
  }

  let sHex = s.toString("hex");

  while (sHex.length < 64) {
    sHex = `0${sHex}`;
  }

  const idHex = byte2hexStr(id);
  const signHex = rHex + sHex + idHex;

  return signHex;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?